# Запрос без кавычек

Tags: php, mysql

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = '$this-user_name'"
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как выполнить запрос без кавычек, выводится

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = 'alexey'"
```

а мне нужно запрос такого плана

```
"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME = alexey"
```

Comment: Зачем нужно? Это будет ошибка синтаксиса, либо вы чего-то не договариваете.

Comment: Скорее всего не так, вот что хочу получить на выходе "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER_HOUSE = 81", а если вставляю $this->user_home в запрос то только с кавычками получается, а мне нужно без них

Comment: Ну так уберите кавычки в первой строке. Но вообще за составление sql-запроса вручную в php уже давно бьют по рукам. Используйте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php